# How do you make a button and connect scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

How do I create a button that links to another scene in my main menu (and by the way it is 2d). I tried the OnGUI code, it did link it to the scene, but it just linked it to the scene straight away after pressing the play button without clicking it.

Answer (score 2):

You need a texture for the button, a nice 2D sprite will do. Just load through the editor. Then you add the code above to a script. Notice that you need an `if`, *or else bad things happen* :D (I could not resist the pun).

If you want to make it so that when you hit a specific button do it like this:

```
var texture: Texture;

function OnGUI()
{
    if(GUI.Button(Rect(10,10,50,50), texture))
       Application.LoadLevel("SceneName");
}
```

Or If you don't want to use the default GUI style provided by Unity you can do this:

```
function OnGUI()
{
    var r = Rect(10,10,50,50);
    GUI.DrawTexture(r,  texture);

    if(Event.current.type == EventType.MouseUp 
       && r.Contains(Event.current.mousePosition))
        Application.LoadLevel("SceneName");
}
```

Both versions of the code allow you to click the button and do something afterwards; in this case is switch scenes.

More on GUI stuff can be found [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gui-Customization.html).

Comment: Hi, the script did work but the thing is, it creates a seperate button, how can i just MAKE A 2D SPRITE to be a button

Comment: @user3696676 I just saw you unaccepted my answer. What do you mean it creates a new button? **My code only creates 1 button**.

Comment: I mean make a picture a button. So when you touch/click it, it takes you to a certain scene

Comment: @user3696676 Ok, try the new code I posted in my answer, it removes the border. In both versions you need to add the picture to the `texture` variable via the editor.